# touch.fingerid touch not working

Tags: c#, touch, unity-game-engine

Below is my mouse look script which controls touch and movement, now I am implementing multiple touch, For, which i used finger-ID, but after implementing this, my touch is'nt working, don't know why. By defult slider_finger_id is =-1;

```
 if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) 
    {
        if( Input.touchCount>0 )
        {
            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
            {
                if (touch_moving_tex.HitTest (touch.position))
                    {
                    if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began &&  touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && slider_finger_id ==-1) 
                        {
                        if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY) 
                        {
                            sensitivityX = main_fov; 
                            noisedeltaX += ((((Mathf.Cos (Time.time) * Random.Range (-10, 10) / 5f) * noiseX) - noisedeltaX) / 100) * Time.timeScale;
                            rotationXtemp += (touch.deltaPosition.x * sensitivityX * sensitivity) + (noisedeltaX);

                            //rotationXtemp += (Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition.x * sensitivityX * sensitivity) + (noisedeltaX);

                            rotationX += ((rotationXtemp - rotationX) / 3) * Time.timeScale;
                            rotationX = Mathf.Clamp (rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);

                            sensitivityY = main_fov;
                            noisedeltaY += ((((Mathf.Sin (Time.time) * Random.Range (-10, 10) / 5f) * noiseY) - noisedeltaY) / 100) * Time.timeScale;

                            rotationYtemp += (touch.deltaPosition.y * sensitivityY * sensitivity) + (noisedeltaY);
                            rotationY += ((rotationYtemp - rotationY) / 3) * Time.timeScale;

                            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
                            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 (-rotationY, rotationX, 0)), 9f * Time.deltaTime);

                        }
                    }
                    slider_finger_id = touch.fingerId;
                    }
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) 
                {
                    if (touch.fingerId == slider_finger_id) 
                    {
                        slider_finger_id = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I noticed one thing that if i dont use slider_finger_id then it works.. but I checked many times it is -1 and nothing is changing it

Comment: And where is `slider_finger_id` setted ? On the first iteration, what is the value ? And I am not sure if `-1` is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was not getting touch.fingerId, and storing, and not checking for specific touch.fingerId, so I figured out by doing this. below is script and performing well. (main thing which I am doing in below code is, touch will work only for for first touch, doing by fingerId by saving touch.fingerId)
first I just checked touch count is greter than zero or not, then getting touches array and performing foreach loop, then checking rather touch is in my desire poistion or not, then getting first touch fingerId, and saves it in slider_finger_id, then using it.

```
if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) 
{
    if( Input.touchCount>0 )
    {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            if (touch_moving_tex.HitTest (touch.position))
                {
                if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began && slider_finger_id == -1) 
                    {
                     slider_finger_id = touch.fingerId;
                    }

                    if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                     {
                    if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY) 
                    {
                        sensitivityX = main_fov; 
                        noisedeltaX += ((((Mathf.Cos (Time.time) * Random.Range (-10, 10) / 5f) * noiseX) - noisedeltaX) / 100) * Time.timeScale;
                        rotationXtemp += (touch.deltaPosition.x * sensitivityX * sensitivity) + (noisedeltaX);

                        //rotationXtemp += (Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition.x * sensitivityX * sensitivity) + (noisedeltaX);

                        rotationX += ((rotationXtemp - rotationX) / 3) * Time.timeScale;
                        rotationX = Mathf.Clamp (rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);

                        sensitivityY = main_fov;
                        noisedeltaY += ((((Mathf.Sin (Time.time) * Random.Range (-10, 10) / 5f) * noiseY) - noisedeltaY) / 100) * Time.timeScale;

                        rotationYtemp += (touch.deltaPosition.y * sensitivityY * sensitivity) + (noisedeltaY);
                        rotationY += ((rotationYtemp - rotationY) / 3) * Time.timeScale;

                        rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
                        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 (-rotationY, rotationX, 0)), 9f * Time.deltaTime);

                    }
                  }
                }
                slider_finger_id = touch.fingerId;
                }
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && slider_finger_id == touch.fingerId) 
            {
                    slider_finger_id = -1;
            }
        }
    }
```